# I want efficient data structure to store items and their counts and search for min of them?

Tags: java, list

I want efficient data structure to store items and their counts and search for min of them?

I have a number of items, and a count of each item, I want a data sturucture to store the items and their counts. in my script each time i will search about an item and update its count, also I want to find the item that has the min count, and some times I want the count of some items. would you please tell me which data structure to use with low space and low cost search operations?

Comment: Is the amount of items to store fixed?

Comment: Seems you want something like a `HashMap<String, Integer>`, storing itemName:count. Quite fast at lookups, streaming the entries will allow for easy  searches for lowest/highest/any condition really.

Comment: @pafauk. You may want to reduce the complexity to find min to *O(1)* with a clever structure.

Comment: the amount of items are not fixed @akuzminykh

Comment: @akuzminykh Yeah sure, you may insert stuff sorted or something. I'll be interested on reading an in-depth answer on something smart, go ahead, I'll surely upvote!

Comment: @pafauk. Nah, it could be even worse. It depends on how often min has to be found, but OP hasn't provided enough information to decide what's really best here.

Comment: Yeah, I also think *O(n)* is probably sufficient here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a `Map`, or, more specifically, a `HashMap` is probably what you're looking for. The lookup complexity is *O(1)*, and finding the lowest or highest is *O(n)*.

```
Map<Item, Long> items = new HashMap<>();
items.put(Item.BANANA, 3L);
items.put(Item.APPLE, 4L);

// Count the bananas
long bananasCount = items.getOrDefault(Item.BANANAS, 0L);
// Get the item with the highest count
items.entrySet().stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
```

There are also other structures, which lets you calculate the minimum and maximum even faster (with complexity *O(1)*), but at the cost of updating probably.

Comment: While this solves the name lookup, it doesn't solve the "minimum count" lookup.  You can beat O(n) on minimum count if you use a different data structure to track counts, as the cost of increasing your insert/update/delete times (by updating both data structures)

Comment: @EdwinBuck At the cost of increasing inserts, you can still do that with a single structure. Just need to keep it sorted by values. But you'll have to cook up your own structure for that.

Comment: @pafauk. If you sort the data structure, it's not indexed by the modulus of the hash value against the bucket size.  So you lose the O(1) lookup.

Comment: True, you lose on lookup - insert/lookup becomes O(log n), and minimum O(1) (e.g using Guava's TreeMultimap). So it's all a matter of balance the OP wants to strike.

Answer (score 1):

You have conflicting requests.

You want fast lookup of an item by it's key (name, item number, id, whatever)
You want fast lookup of an item by it's quantity on hand (count)

Since the fastest lookup possible would be something like a map, which has O(1) lookup, the question is "which key would you use?"  Count is conflicting, so you'll get a little less than the ideal O(1); and, name or id will mean you'll have to lookup a lot of items to get the low quantity items.

This means you need two data structures.

One would be the typical map of name/id to the item.
One would be an index of quantity to a list of items with that quantity.

This means you'll have to update both data structures at the same time, to keep you data consistent within the application.

And then you want to pull up lists of items efficently.  Well, we don't have any idea if your lists are stable, or may be randomly selected, so I would just go over the list item by item.  If you knew you had stable, long lived (reused) lists, another approach might be better.

I hope you read between the lines in this commentary.  There is no "efficient" data structure without considering the use cases.  While you already show that you know that; there is another level to it.  When you combine multiple conflicting use cases, sometimes you wind up sacraficing efficiency in one for efficency in others.  For example, to get fast lookup, you're now going to reduce your insert/update times by needing to rebuild another different data structure.

Of course, you could also require (in the future) your data structure to grow beyond the capacity of a single machine.  If so, you might find that all of your solutions aren't that great, as they all assume a single memory address space.  Then you'll probably have to shift to a distributed data model, like Apache Spark/Hadoop.  In that space, building an index might make less sense, as filtering results is an incredibly cheap operation, while building a distributed index can become even more expensive.  So, you might just shift to "read all entries, throwing away the ones I don't want" and that might service you well, depending on the data, the required latencies, and the actual use in operation.

The key here is to benchmark, and to know what is "good enough."  If you get hung up in "best" or "most efficient" you will spend far more money makeing fast things fast.  Instead set some benchmarks that read like "must be returned from a set of (some number) in under X milliseconds" and then build your solution to beat that rule.

Answer (score -1):

for example:
I have items 
key:     Count:
A        2
B        3

### C        1

for the above list, I want to add new items with count 1 and may i want to increment the count of the existing items A,B,C. also, I want to get the count of some items for example the count of A, the answer should be 2. also i want to get the item that has the min count which should be 1 in our example.
for my problem i want to do the operation with min time and min space!!
thanks a lot for  your replies

Answer (score -3):

List is good option to use here and you can use stream API(Java 8 and above) to do operations like finding min and counting elements based on some condition.

You can find stream usage example here

https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams